# ERROR 7405 --- [ main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application startup failed

Tags: java, gradle, spring-security, spring-boot

I am using Gradle 2.9 and springBootVersion = '1.3.1.RELEASE'
 Build is successful but jar deployment is not successful. These are my    logs:

```
2016-02-05 20:44:13.905  WARN 7405 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/internal/ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work
2016-02-05 20:44:13.916  INFO 7405 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2016-02-05 20:44:13.942 ERROR 7405 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/internal/ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at com.opensecret.OpenSecretApplication.main(OpenSecretApplication.java:10) [open-secret-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53) [open-secret-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/internal/ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.doLoadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:178) ~[open-secret-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:142) ~[open-secret-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    ... 27 common frames omitted

2016-02-05 20:44:13.958  WARN 7405 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' is defined)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/internal/ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113)
    at com.opensecret.OpenSecretApplication.main(OpenSecretApplication.java:10)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/internal/ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$Work
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.doLoadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 27 more
```

This my gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.3.1.RELEASE'
        hibernateVersion = '5.0.7.Final'
        mysqlVersion = '5.1.6'
        junitVersion = '4.12'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
    }
}

apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 

jar {
    baseName = 'open-secret'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${springBootVersion}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBootVersion}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:${springBootVersion}")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-core:${hibernateVersion}")
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:${mysqlVersion}")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion}")
    testCompile("junit:junit:${junitVersion}")
    testCompile("org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19")
}


eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}
```

This is my Controller:

```
    package com.opensecret.controller;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
    import com.opensecret.model.User;
    import com.opensecret.repository.UserRepository;

    import java.util.List;

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value="/api/user")
    public class UserController {

        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepository;

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public List<User> findAll() {
            return userRepository.findAll();
        }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public User add(@RequestBody User user) {
            User model = new User();
            model.setEmail(user.getEmail());
            model.setName(user.getEmail());
            return userRepository.saveAndFlush(model);
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public User findOne(@PathVariable int id) {
            return userRepository.findOne(id);
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
        public User update(@PathVariable int id, @RequestBody User user) {
            User model = userRepository.findOne(id);
            if (model != null) {
                model.setName(user.getName());
                model.setEmail(user.getEmail());
                return userRepository.saveAndFlush(model);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
        public void delete(@PathVariable int id) {
            userRepository.delete(id);
        }
    }

This is my model:
package com.opensecret.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 80)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 80)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

This is my Security Config:

```
package com.opensecret.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .httpBasic().and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

This is my Repository:

```
import com.opensecret.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Integer>{
}
```

This is application.properties:

```
server.port: 9000
management.port: 9001
management.address: 127.0.0.1

spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/opensecret
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

And this is main:

```
package com.opensecret;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class OpenSecretApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OpenSecretApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Please someone help me I am not able to understand why it's happening...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a mixture of Hibernate versions on the classpath as a result of `hibernateVersion` being set to `5.0.7.Final` and your `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and `hibernate-core` dependencies:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-datajpa:${springBootVersion}")
compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-core:${hibernateVersion}")
```

`spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` depends on `hibernate-entitymanager` 4.3.11.Final which, in turn, depends on `hibernate-core`. You've overridden the version of the latter so you've got `hibernate-entitymanager` 4.3.11 mixed with `hibernate-core` 5.0.7.Final.

The simplest solution is to replace your dependency on `hibernate-core` with one on `hibernate-entitymanager` so that your dependencies look like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${springBootVersion}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBootVersion}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:${springBootVersion}")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:${hibernateVersion}")
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:${mysqlVersion}")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion}")
    testCompile("junit:junit:${junitVersion}")
    testCompile("org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19")
}
```

I'd recommend you take things a step further, though. Spring Boot's Gradle plugin provides dependency management for itself and several third-party libraries that means that you don't need to specify a version when you declare a dependency. If you take advantage of that and remove some dependencies that are pulled in transitively, you can simplify your `build.gradle` to this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.1.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

jar {
    baseName = 'open-secret'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext['hibernate.version'] = '5.0.7.Final'

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}


eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}
```

Note the `ext['hibernate.version'] = '5.0.7.Final'` that is being used to override Spring Boot's default Hibernate version (4.3.11.Final) to the one that you want.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Andy Wilkinson. The first one that you told to replace dependency on hibernate-core with one on hibernate-entitymanager is not working for me. But second one where I'm overriding Spring Boot's default Hibernate version (4.3.11.Final) to ext['hibernate.version'] = '5.0.7.Final' is working fine for me.... Thank you again.